# Spring Tool Suite Integration Graph Custom Elements

Tags: graph, spring-integration, spring-tool-suite

Is it possible to display custom namespace elements to the Spring Tool Suite Integration Graph view? I found the following post form 2013. Does anyone know if there is an update in STS?

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/725929-sts-spring-integration-graph

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you still can't see custom elements on SI Graph. Please open an issue here against STS to keep track of this: https://issuetracker.springsource.com